# execute tcl commands line by line

Tags: tcl

I have a file like this:

```
set position        {0.50 0.50}
set visibility      false
set text {ID: {entity.id}\n Value: {entity.contour_val}}
```

And I want to do something similar to source, but I want to use a file handle only.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
proc readArray {fileHandle arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName arr

    set cl 0

    while {! [eof $fileHandle]} {
        set cl [expr "$cl + 1"]
        set line [gets $fileHandle]
        if [$line eq {}] continue

        puts $line
        namespace eval ::__esg_priv "

            uplevel 1 {*}$line
        "

        info vars ::__esg_priv::*

        foreach varPath [info vars ::__esg_priv::*] {

            set varName [string map { ::__esg_priv:: "" } $varPath]

            puts "Setting arr($varName) -> [set $varPath]"

            set arr($varName) [set $varPath]
        }
        namespace delete __esg_priv
    }       
    puts "$cl number of lines read"
}
```

In place of uplevel I tried many combinations of eval and quoting. 
My problem is, it either fails on the lines with lists or it does not actuall set the variables.
What is the right way to do it, if the executed commands are expected to be any valid code.

An extra question would be how to properly apply error checking, which I haven't tried yet.

After a call to

```
readArray [open "myFile.tcl" r] arr
```

I expect that

```
parray arr
```

issues something like:

```
arr(position)   = 0.50 0.50
arr(text)       = ID: {entity.id}\n Value: {entity.contour_val}
arr(visibility) = false
```

BTW: The last line contains internal {}, which are supposed to make it into the string variables. And there is no intent to make this a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, but there are still some problems with it:

```
proc readArray {fileHandle arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName arr

    set cl 0

    while {! [eof $fileHandle]} {
        incr cl ;# !
        set line [gets $fileHandle]
        if {$line eq {}} continue ;# !

        puts $line
        namespace eval ::__esg_priv $line ;# !

        foreach varPath [info vars ::__esg_priv::*] {
            set varName [string map { ::__esg_priv:: "" } $varPath]

            puts "Setting arr($varName) -> [set $varPath]"

            set arr($varName) [set $varPath]
        }
        namespace delete __esg_priv
    }       
    puts "$cl number of lines read"
}
```

I've taken out a couple of lines that didn't seem necessary, and changed some lines a bit.

You don't need `set cl [expr "$cl + 1"]`: `incr cl` will do.

`if [$line eq {}] continue` will fail because the `[...]` is a command substitution. `if {$line eq {}} continue` (braces instead of brackets) does what you intend.

Unless you are accessing variables in another scope, you won't need `uplevel`. `namespace eval ::__esg_priv $line` will evaluate one line in the designated namespace.

I didn't change the following, but maybe you should:

`set varName [string map { ::__esg_priv:: "" } $varPath]` works as intended, but `set varName [namespace tail $varPath]` is cleaner.

Be aware that if there exists a global variable with the same name as one of the variables in your file, no namespace variable will be created; the global variable will be updated instead.

If you intend to use the value in the `text` variable as a dictionary, you need to remove either the `\n` or the braces.

According to your question title, you want to evaluate the file line by line. If that requirement can be lifted, your code could be simplified by reading the whole script in one operation and then evaluating it with a single `namespace eval`.

**ETA**

This solution is a lot more robust in that it reads the script in a sandbox (always a good idea when writing code that will execute arbitrary external code) and redefines (within that sandbox) the `set` command to create members in your array instead of regular variables.

```
proc readArray {fileHandle arrayName} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName arr
    set int [interp create -safe]
    $int alias set apply {{name value} {
        uplevel 1 [list set arr($name) $value]
    }}
    $int eval [read $fileHandle]
    interp delete $int
}
```

To make it even more safe against unexpected interaction with global variables etc, look at the `interp` package in the Tcllib. It lets you create an interpreter that is completely empty.

Documentation: [apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm), [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [eof](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eof.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [interp](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/interp/tcllib_interp.html) package, [interp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable comments and improvements. Though, it does still not seem to do what I want. I will try to edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: @Ingo: the result you expect is exactly what I get when I run my code and print the array. What are you getting?

Comment: Interesting. The array is not defined for me. I will double check.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Looks like I corrupted my environment. I am running in a host application and after restarting that, it started to work. Maybe due to the open file handle...

Comment: @Ingo: good. Regarding your secondary question on error handling, I think it would be better to post a new question for that since that is another matter.